# How to map the root URL in an ASP.NET application?

Tags: asp.net, httphandler

I have the following in my Web.config:

```
<httpHandlers>
    . . .
    <add verb="GET,HEAD" path="/" type="Vis.Web.BootHandler, Vis" />
</httpHandlers>
```

That HTTP handler returns a static HTML page, just to see if it works.

Now when I run my web application (which has no Default.aspx or the likes) I get the default directory listing instead. When I change the path to `"/foo"` it works perfectly fine.

I tried `""` for the path, it yields the directory listing as well. Same having it as `"/foo"` and then adding a URL mapping to for `""`, `"~"`, `"~/"` and `"/"`

How do I handle the web root / override the directory listing with a HTTP handler?

Comment: Thank you! This was a helpful question. I was trying to do the same thing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**UPDATED: Regarding comment** 
This can't be done in the development server as it requires a feature of IIS.

**ORIGINAL:**
You need to add a wildcard application mapping to the asp.net DLL so that all requestes (even for directories) are run through the .net runtime and therefore your HTTP Handler.

Check out http://www.microsoft.com/technet/prodtechnol/windowsserver2003/library/IIS/5c5ae5e0-f4f9-44b0-a743-f4c3a5ff68ec.mspx

for more info

Comment: Thanks, very helpful. Can it also be done for the built-in web server in Visual Web Developer?

Comment: Too bad it doesn't work on the development server then, but at least being able to do it with IIS is a big improvement.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to what @Greg B said you will need to add a dummy default.aspx page and register your handler using /* path:

```
<httpHandlers>
    . . .
    <add verb="GET,HEAD" path="/*" type="Vis.Web.BootHandler, Vis" />
</httpHandlers>
```